# Determining whether a matrix is positive semi-definite using the axioms of the inner-product

Tags: matrices, probability-theory

Assume that $V_i,V_j,D$ are all dependent random variables and real-valued, and let the matrix $H$ be defined by

$$
H_{ij} = \mathrm E(V_i V_j) - \mathrm E(\mathrm E(V_i\mid D)\mathrm E(V_j\mid D))
$$

My goal is to determine whether $H$ is positive semi-definite, it is the Hessian of a log-likelihood function that I would like to know whether it is convex.

If I can show that $\langle V_i, V_j \rangle = H_{ij}$ is an inner product then $H$ is Gramian and so it is positive semi-definite.

The first two axioms for an inner-product follows directly

$$
\langle V_i, V_j \rangle = \langle V_j, V_i \rangle 
$$
$$
\langle aV_i, V_j \rangle = a \langle V_j, V_i \rangle
$$

Now, to determine whether the third axiom holds

$$
\langle V_i, V_i \rangle \geq 0
$$

I need to determine whether it is true that

$$
\mathrm E(V_i^2) - \mathrm E(\mathrm E(V_i\mid D)^2) \geq 0
$$

$$
\mathrm E(V_i^2) - \mathrm E(V_i)^2 \geq 0
$$

$$
Var(V_i) \geq 0
$$

From Schwarz' inequality $\mathrm E(V_i)^2 \leq \mathrm E(V_i^2)$, so $\langle V_i, V_i \rangle \geq 0$ is true.

I am quite far from my comfort zone. Is my reasoning OK?

Update: 
Would also be interesting to hear about other ways that one can prove $H_{ij}$ is positive-semi-definite.

Comment: For SEMI-definite, you don't need to show that $Var(V_i)=0$ off $V_i=0$.

Comment: @Fabian, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still can't see anything wrong with the approach in the question.

I figured out an alternative way to prove it:

$$
H_{ij} = \mathrm E(V_i V_j) - \mathrm E(\mathrm E(V_i\mid D)\mathrm E(V_j\mid D))
$$

Noting that 
$$
\begin{align}
Cov(X,Y|Z) & = E[(X-E[X|Z])(Y-E[Y|Z])] \\
           & = E[XY] - E[X|Z]E[Y|Z]
\end{align}
$$

We get

$$
H_{ij} = E[Cov(V_i,V_j|Z)]
$$

Let

$$
A_{ij} = Cov(V_i,V_j|Z)
$$

Which is positive semidefinite

$$
x^TAx \geq 0  \quad \forall x
$$

also
$$
E[x^TAx] =x^TE[A]x = x^THx \geq 0  \quad \forall x
$$

So $H$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: If anyone else answers the original question, I will accept that as the answer instead.